# Cant get Objects out of Arraylist, .get()

Tags: android, list, object

so I am trying to create a list of objects that I can then access later.

I've been able to fill an `ArrayList` with the objects but have not been able to get the objects back out as the  app crashes whenever I attempt to use .get(1)

Activity class

```
 public class Second_Activity extends Activity {
 ArrayList<Event> Eventlist = new ArrayList<Event>();
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);


 public void Add(View view) {
    EditText Title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETtitle);
    EditText Subject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETsubject);
    EditText room = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETroom);
    EditText time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETtime);

    String FTitle =  Title.getText().toString();
    String FSubject = Subject.getText().toString();
    String Froom = room.getText().toString();
    String FTtime = time.getText().toString();
    Event ev = new Event(FTitle,FSubject,Froom,FTtime);
    Eventlist.add(ev);
     String name= Eventlist.get(1).getRoom();
    }
  }
```

Event Class

```
   public class Event {
   String Title;
   String Subject;
   String Room;
   String StartTime;

   public Event(String Title , String Subject, String Room, String  StartTime)
   {       

   }
   public void setTitle(String title) {
     Title = title;
   }
   public void setSubject(String subject) {
     Subject = subject;
   }
   public void setRoom(String room) {
     this.Room = room;
   }
   public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
     StartTime = startTime;
   }
   public String getStartTime() {
     return StartTime;
   }
   public String getRoom() {
     return Room;
   }
   public String getTitle() {
     return Title;
   }
   public String getSubject() {
     return Subject;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Java's basics: arrays are using 0 based indexing

Comment: improved readability of request and segmented code blocks

Answer (score 0):

> Array indexing start with 0 ... first object will be at position 0 ... you are trying to access 2 item  which not there is list

```
  String name= Eventlist.get(0).getRoom();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing data at index 1. Starting index for ArrayList is 0. As first time it has only  one item in it, i.e. at index 0, try to access index 0 instead of 1.

Comment: It worked thanks, just hit a wall when thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have added only one Item to your `ArrayList` and 
second you haven't initialize your parameters from `constructor` of class `Event`  .

So get your object from 0th position not from one because index is started from zero not from one.

```
 String name= Eventlist.get(0).getRoom();



     public class Event {
       String Title;
       String Subject;
       String Room;
       String StartTime;

       public Event(String Title , String Subject, String Room, String  StartTime)
       {       
//here you need set incoming values to your class variables .

         this.Title =Title;
         this.Subject=Subject;
         this.Room=Room;
         this.StartTime=StartTime;

       }
       public void setTitle(String title) {
         Title = title;
       }
       public void setSubject(String subject) {
         Subject = subject;
       }
       public void setRoom(String room) {
         this.Room = room;
       }
       public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
         StartTime = startTime;
       }
       public String getStartTime() {
         return StartTime;
       }
       public String getRoom() {
         return Room;
       }
       public String getTitle() {
         return Title;
       }
       public String getSubject() {
         return Subject;
       }
      }
```

Comment: is this help you . :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to initial the variables in the class and start from 0 instead of 1.